# Trace clicking behavior of visitors of on web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing my own home page in `html` and `javascript`.

I have many hyperlinks on the home page, which interests me is, how many times visitors of  my page click on them.

For instance, `<a href="paper.pdf">pdf</a>` is a hyperlink which directs to downloading a pdf file. I would like to set up a mechanism of counter of clicking on it. For instance this information is automatically recorded in a file so that I could check it from time to time.

Besides counter, other information such as the time of clicking, the IP of visitors who click interest me too. It will be great if I can record them.

I don't know `javascript`, could anyone suggest me an efficient way to realize this with details (or a piece of code)?

Answer (score 1):

As per you code

```
<a href="some.pdf" id="uniqueID">PDF</a>
```

You can see I have added one ID in the PDF link, now

```
$("#uniqueID").click(function(){
//Write a ajax function to calculate the count and storing
});
```

I have not written the entire code, I think it's sufficient for you to understand the logic.

Comment: Well, I always understand the logic... this question is quite about the details... for instance, how to specify the file to write, how to declare the counter, what is the function to get IP and time...

Comment: I googled a little bit... do I really need `php`? I don't want it to be a `sql` database, a log `txt` file would be fine...

Comment: You must use any server side language to read/write the data into the file or database. Otherwise you have to use HTML5 storage. In PHP there are functions are available to get the IP etc.

Comment: @SoftTimur you can easily do it using jQuery AJAX and PHP to write to .txt file without a mySQL db.